# Static position within Flow layout panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been trying, for hours, using different implementations with background images and Paint handlers, to set a fade over a list of labels in a FlowLayoutPanel.

The list is horizontal (`wrap=false`), and automatically scrolls to the end (the last item is continually scrolled into view), which is why I wish to apply the fade at the start (so you can see that there are more items out of view).

I believe if I can fix a label at the start, having it hover over the other labels in the Panel, I can then draw the background over.

I tried adding the label over the Panel itself, but it is not transparent over the panel, just a white box...

Is this possible?

Comment: Share code, put images to explain better, this is not a good way to ask a question.

Comment: Made relevant edits.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943454/winforms-how-to-create-a-control-transparent-to-other-controls